# Getting vBulletin data in an external directory

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, magento-1.9, vbulletin

I am trying to get vbulletin session variables eg: userID and username from an external page/file in the parent directory of vbulletin(in a magento installation).
I have followed the steps suggested for this process as follows.

```
    <?php
    global $vbulletin;
$curdir = getcwd();
chdir($curdir.'/forum');
require_once('./global.php');

//Use $bbuserinfo. 
echo('userid: ' . $vbulletin->userinfo['userid']);
echo('username: ' . $vbulletin->userinfo['username']);
chdir($curdir);  
    ?>
```

i would then echo data like the following code

```
<?php echo $vbulletin->userinfo['username']; ?>
```

This works perfectly inside the vbulletin directory however it returns Unregistered for username and 0 for userid and it also logs me out of the current vbulletin session aswell.

I have checked that
1.Path to Save Cookies set to "Suggested Settings '/'  "
2.`$bbuserinfo['userid']` doesnt work
3.`$vbulletin->userinfo['userid']` and `$vbulletin->userinfo['username']` return 0 and Unregistered respectively
4.code is correct for vbulletin version 4.2.3 as suggested

Can anyone advise me how to correctly get the vbulletin session variables(userid and username)/[PHP]$vbulletin->userinfo[/PHP] array of the current logged in user in an external directory to the vbulletin installation.

> NOTE: I am experiencing a failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in autoload.php error in the magento directory (parent directory) where I used the above code which I doubt is related to the problem at hand

Please feel free to ask for any additional info.
Thanks a ton:).

Answer (score 2):

this works for me from every path on my server outside the vBulletin directory:

```
$curdir = getcwd();
chdir('/absolute/path/to/your/vbulletin/');
define('DIE_QUIETLY', 1);
define('NO_REGISTER_GLOBALS', 1);
define('NOCOOKIES', 1);
define('SESSION_BYPASS', 1);
define('THIS_SCRIPT', 'my_external_script');

$globaltemplates = array();
$specialtemplates = array();
$actiontemplates = array();
$phrasegroups = array();

require_once('./includes/init.php');
$vbphrase = init_language();
require('./includes/functions_user.php');

echo $vbulletin->userinfo['userid'];

chdir($curdir);
```